# How can I create an object and store it in an array list in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, object

I've just never done it before and after reading a few forum posts its still as clear as mud.

Help would be much appreichated! Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: You can't store an object in an ArrayList, you can only store a reference to an object in an array list.

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<?>();
Object o = new Object();
list.add(o);
```

Comment: This code will not compile.

Comment: Err, I think it will compile.  maybe you have an old JVM.